# No default constructor exists for class error

Tags: c++, constructor

Some simple code:

```
class Thing {
public:
    int num;
    Thing(int num) { 
        this->num = num; 
    }
};

class Stuff {
public:
    Thing thing;  // an instance of thing is declared here but it cannot construct it
    Stuff(Thing thing) {
        this->thing = thing;
    }
};

int main() {
    Thing thing = Thing(5);
    Stuff stuff = Stuff(thing);
}
```

So here, I'm trying to work out how I should be taking a new instance of Thing in the constructor of Stuff without pointing to it as I want Stuff to hold its own copy. Of course, I can't declare thing like I have above because it's trying to initialise it.

How can I get around this problem of assigning a new object copy to a class' variable through its constructor?

Exact error is:

```
In constructor 'Stuff::Stuff(Thing)':
error: no matching function for call to 'Thing::Thing()'
  Stuff(Thing thing){ this->thing = thing; }

candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Comment: Once you declared any constructor explicitly for `class Thing`, then no default constructor is automatically generated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Stuff(Thing thing) {
    this->thing = thing;
}
```

By the time you enter the constructor's body, the compiler will have already initialized your object's data members.  But it can't initialize `thing` because it does not have a default constructor.

The solution is to tell the compiler how to initialize it by using an *initlizer list*.

```
Stuff(Thing thing) : thing(thing) {
    // Nothing left to do.
}
```

This is less typing, cleaner code and more efficient.  (More efficient, because if the variable is going to be initialized anyway, then why initialize it with an unwanted value first just to assign another one as quickly as you can?  Of course, since your current code doesn't even compile, “more efficient” is a somewhat dubious statement, here.)

Comment: Again, just what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize thing member in Stuff with initializer list:

```
class Stuff {
public:
    Thing thing;  // an instance of thing is declared here but it cannot construct it
    Stuff(Thing thing): thing(thing) { }
};
```

Comment: No problem! I would also name the member variable something different like mThing or m_Thing to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The only constructor for `Thing` takes an `int` parameter.

Thus, when you declare:

```
Thing thing;
```

With no arguments, how does it know what `num` should be?

As the error states, there is 1 expected, but none provided. You need to either add a default constructor:

```
Thing::Thing(void) : num(0){};
```

or alternatively modify the argument:

```
Thing::Thing(int num=0)
```

In both cases I have used `0`, but this should be whatever you think `num` should be 'by default', when nothing is specified.

Without this, `Stuff`'s `Thing` must have a value to initialise it; this is supported via the initialisation list, which you neglected to use in your `Thing::Thing` (see above), and as a side-note your `this->num` is not necessary, `num` is sufficient.

```
Stuff::Stuff(Thing inThing) : thing(inThing){};
```

Comment: Exactly my question. How can I store a copy of type Thing in the Stuff class as a property that any member of Stuff can access from any method?

Comment: @Jazcash Initialise it in `Stuff` constructor's init list.